# Same size for multiple plots on different pages

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a MWE:

````
---
output:
    pdf_document
title: Multiple plots on multiple pages
---

\newpage

```{r}
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- qplot(1:10,1:10)
p2 <- qplot(1:10,11:20)


myplots  = list(p1,p2)

plot_grid(plotlist = myplots,ncol = 2)
```
\newpage

```{r}
p1 <- qplot(1:10,1:10)
p2 <- qplot(1:10,11:20)

p3 <- qplot(1:10,21:30)
p4 <- qplot(1:10,31:40)
p5 <- qplot(1:10,41:50)
p6 <- qplot(1:10,51:60)

myplots  = list(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6)

plot_grid(plotlist = myplots,ncol = 2)

```
````

I have 2 plots on the second page and 6 plots on the third page. Because there are 2 plots on page 2,they are bigger in size and there 6 plots on page 3,they are smaller in size.

How can I have that EACH individual plot is the same size on both the pages ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to manually specify the figure height in R-chunk to fit your needs. In your case, the first chunk for 1-row grid can be set as `{r, fig.height = 3}` while the second chunk for the 3-rows grid can be set as `{r, fig.height = 9}`. The number is optional but you must maintain the proportion (in this case 1:3).

Comment: Many thanks. Is there a way of automating this ?

Comment: It was the simplest solution that I can think of as long as you don't have to much figure to adjust. You can consider this blog post: http://michaeljw.com/blog/post/subchunkify/ to set a function that can help you do in-line re-chunk with other preferred sizes.